CORS Policy Error with Specific Data in React and Django Application
CORS Policy Error with Specific Data in React and Django Application
I'm experiencing an issue with CORS policy in my React frontend and Django backend application. The error message I'm receiving is:
Access to fetch at backend URL' from origin 'frontend URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
I have configured all the CORS Configuration in settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [ 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', ] CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'] CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [ 'accept', 'accept-encoding', 'authorization', 'content-type', 'dnt', 'origin', 'user-agent', 'x-csrftoken', 'x-requested-with',]
Installed apps also 'corsheader' is added

The problem is i am getting this issue for only one data not for all data

for my views i added Decorators like:
@csrf_exempt @require_http_methods(["OPTIONS", "POST"])
As it is working fine in Local,Development only for Staging i am getting this issue that to for only some data others are working fine

Have you added your react app host name to the allowed hosts?

@MustafaReda yes Added still i am getting the Same issue and in Dev,local and all its working fine only for Staging its throwing the issue

did you install django-cors-headers?
